# Play 2.0 ManyToMany and ManyToOne

Tags: java, playframework

I try to save and show a many to one relation with play webframework 2.0...

I have these models:

```
@Entity
public class Project extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String name; 

    @ManyToMany
    public List<Worker> workers = 
          new ArrayList<Worker>();

    @ManyToOne
    public Worker head;
...

}


@Entity
public class Worker extends Model{  
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String name;

   ...

    public static Map<String,String> options() {
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        for(Worker w: Worker.getAll()) {
            options.put(w.id.toString(), w.name);
        }
        return options;
    }       

}
```

and I have this view:

```
@(projects: List[Project], taskForm: Form[Project])

@import helper._


    <h1>@projects.size() Projects(s)</h1>

    <ul>
        @for(project <- projects) {
            <li>
                @project.name
                <b> - head: </b>
                @project.head.name

                <ul>
                @for(worker <- project.workers) {
                    <li>
                        @worker.name
                    </li>
                }
                </ul>

                @form(routes.ProjectController.deleteProject(project.id)) {
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                }

            </li>
        }
    </ul>

    <h2>Add a new task</h2>

    @form(routes.ProjectController.newProject()) {        

        @inputText(taskForm("name"))

        @inputText(taskForm("description"))               

        @select(
            taskForm("head.id"), 
            options(Worker.options), 
            '_label -> "Worker"         
        )       


        <input type="submit" value="Create">

    }
```

But when i save the project I have no associated workers in head
and I didn't find any many to many example..
Can anyone show me how to manage relation in play 2.0 or show me a link that explain it?

thanks to all replies

Comment: what you mean "I save the project"?

Comment: when I save a model bean "Project" from the form in the view

Comment: I am currently trying to write something very similar but I don't get it ... could you maybe post your controller to make your solution more clear? Would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used a method getAll to get all projects and pass them to the view...
I saw that I need to do "fetch('workers')" to have workers attached to the project...

I missed fetch method after getAll in the controller... problem solved...